# What does fiducial distribution do?

Tags: inference, fiducial

I have two questions about fiducial inference.
does fiducial inference compute a confidence interval or a point estimate?

- What is a fiducial distribution and where are we going to use it
  because in my research three is just about fiducial interval.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that modern work on fiducial inference by Jan Hannig and others is to some extent different in that respect from the original "philosophy" by Fisher. Are you rather interested in the former or in the latter? (In any case don't necessarily expect me to answer as this requires some time and I don't know whether I'll find it.)

Comment: Also related [What is the fiducial argument and why has it not been accepted?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/what-is-the-fiducial-argument-and-why-has-it-not-been-accepted)